# Is convolution slower in Numpy than in Matlab?

Tags: python, performance, matlab, numpy, convolution

Convolution in Matlab appears to be twice as fast as convolution in Numpy.

Python code (takes 19 seconds on my machine):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
import time

img = np.ones((512,512,512))
kernel = np.ones((5,5,5))/125

start_time = time.time()
ndimage.convolve(img,kernel,mode='constant')
print "Numpy execution took ", (time.time() - start_time), "seconds"
```

Matlab code (takes 8.7 seconds on my machine):

```
img = ones(512,512,512);
kernel = ones(5,5,5) / 125;
tic
convn(img, kernel, 'same');
toc
```

The two give identical results.

Is there a way to improve Numpy to match or beat Matlab's performance here?

Interestingly, this factor or ~2 difference in runtimes is consistent at many input sizes.

Comment: It's not really Python's performance you're timing here, but NumPy/SciPy's. Can you improve those modules' performance? Sure, but not by writing Python code.

Comment: Edited (s/Python/Numpy/).

Comment: You might look into what libraries numpy is built against vs matlab. I know from personal experience that when numpy is built against Intel's MKL library, I get much better performance for some operations than with the defaults.

Comment: This question is ill-posed! A simple `tic toc` is NOT suitable for measuring performance. Use the `timeit` class in numpy and, e.g., this counterpart from [fileexchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18798) for MATLAB. In the documentation there, you also find some indicators on what is wrong with using simply `tic toc`.

Comment: @Jan: I just tested it, and for this specific case, the alternate Matlab and Python functions for timing gave identical results. But, I will definitely use them in future for more accurate timing.

Comment: @JoshAdel - Very true in general, but in this specific case, it shouldn't (?) matter much. `ndimage` doesn't make a ton of BLAS calls, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @JoshAdel: I'm running the MKL version provided with the WinPython distribution: https://code.google.com/p/winpython/wiki/ChangeLog_27 I just double-checked it against Christof Gohlke's version of MKL NumPy (http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) and got the same time result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What exact operation are you doing?  There are a number of optimizations that `ndimage` provides if you don't need general N-d convolution.

For example, your current operation:

```
img = np.ones((512,512,512))
kernel = np.ones((5,5,5))/125
result = ndimage.convolve(img, kernel)
```

is equivalent to:

```
img = np.ones((512,512,512))
result = ndimage.uniform_filter(img, 5)
```

However, there's a large difference in execution speed:

```
In [22]: %timeit ndimage.convolve(img, kernel)
1 loops, best of 3: 25.9 s per loop

In [23]: %timeit ndimage.uniform_filter(img, 5)
1 loops, best of 3: 8.69 s per loop
```

The difference is caused by `uniform_filter` preforming a 1-d convolution along each axis, instead of a generic 3D convolution.

In cases where the kernel is symmetric, you can make these simplifications and get a significant speed up.

I'm not certain about `convn`, but often matlab's functions make these kind of optimizations behind-the-scenes if your input data matches certain criteria.  Scipy more commonly uses one-algorithm-per-function, and expects the user to know which one to pick in which case.

---

You mentioned a "Laplacian of Gaussian" filter. I always get a touch confused with terminology here.

I think what you want in terms of `ndimage` functions is either [`scipy.ndimage.gaussian_laplace`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_laplace.html#scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_laplace) or `scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter` with `order=2` (which filters by the second derivative of the gaussian).

At any rate, both simplify the operation down to a 1-d convolution over each axis, which should give a significant (2-3x) speedup.

Comment: Good thought! I'm working on a 3D segmentation problem, so the filter I really need to run is a 3D Laplacian of Gaussian (AKA Mexican Hat). Replacing Matlab's kernel with `kernel = rand(5,5,5);` didn't change its execution time, though, so I don't think Matlab is cheating here :)

Comment: Ah, yeah, I guess matlab isn't "cheating", then! :)

Comment: I think you want `scipy.ndimage.gaussian_laplace`, but I'm not 100% sure...  I always get slightly confused with the differences between the various edge filters.  Hope the suggestion helps a bit, at any rate!

Answer (score 3):

Not an anwer; just a comment:

Before you compare performance, you need to make sure the two functions are returning the same result:

If Matlab's convn returns the same result as Octave's convn, then 
`convn` is different than `ndimage.convolve`:

```
octave> convn(ones(3,3), ones(2,2))
ans =

   1   2   2   1
   2   4   4   2
   2   4   4   2
   1   2   2   1

In [99]: ndimage.convolve(np.ones((3,3)), np.ones((2,2)))
Out[99]: 
array([[ 4.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 4.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 4.,  4.,  4.]])
```

`ndimage.convolve` has other modes, `'reflect','constant','nearest','mirror', 'wrap'`, but none of these match `convn`'s default ("full") behavior.

---

For 2D arrays, `scipy.signal.convolve2d` is faster than `scipy.signal.convolve`.

For 3D arrays, `scipy.signal.convolve` seems to have the same behavior as `convn(A,B)`:

```
octave> x = convn(ones(3,3,3), ones(2,2,2))
x =

ans(:,:,1) =

   1   2   2   1
   2   4   4   2
   2   4   4   2
   1   2   2   1

ans(:,:,2) =

   2   4   4   2
   4   8   8   4
   4   8   8   4
   2   4   4   2

ans(:,:,3) =

   2   4   4   2
   4   8   8   4
   4   8   8   4
   2   4   4   2

ans(:,:,4) =

   1   2   2   1
   2   4   4   2
   2   4   4   2
   1   2   2   1

In [109]: signal.convolve(np.ones((3,3,3), dtype='uint8'), np.ones((2,2,2), dtype='uint8'))
Out[109]: 
array([[[1, 2, 2, 1],
        [2, 4, 4, 2],
        [2, 4, 4, 2],
        [1, 2, 2, 1]],

       [[2, 4, 4, 2],
        [4, 8, 8, 4],
        [4, 8, 8, 4],
        [2, 4, 4, 2]],

       [[2, 4, 4, 2],
        [4, 8, 8, 4],
        [4, 8, 8, 4],
        [2, 4, 4, 2]],

       [[1, 2, 2, 1],
        [2, 4, 4, 2],
        [2, 4, 4, 2],
        [1, 2, 2, 1]]], dtype=uint8)
```

---

Note that `np.ones((n,m,p))` creates a *float* array by default. Matlab `ones(n,m,p)` appears to create an array of ints. To make a good comparison, you should try to match the dtype of the numpy arrays to the type of the Matlab matrices.

Comment: Just on a side note, `scipy.signal.convolve2d` defaults to the same behavior as matlab/octave's `conv`.  In `scipy.signal`, the `mode` kwarg controls the size of the result (similar to matlab's `conv`), while in `ndimage`, the `mode` kwarg (mostly) controls the boundary conditions.   It's a naming convention that leads to a lot of confusion when comparing things...

Comment: Matlab's ones() makes a matrix of doubles, so the types do in fact match.

Comment: @naroom - Still, if you don't need floats, using ints will give a ~20x speedup, in this case.

Comment: @Joe: Hmm. Ideally I'd like floats, but an integer approximation would do if I could get that kind of speedup. But, when I changed the definitions to `img = np.ones((512,512,512),dtype=np.int)` and `kernel = np.ones((5,5,5),dtype=np.int)`, the runtime stayed the same. Is there a different function I should be running?

Comment: @naroom - Hmm... It went from 25s down to ~1s for me... Let me double-check that...

Comment: @Joe: If it works, submit the code as an answer, and you'll be our winner! Matlab forces its convn to take float input, so that optimization is impossible to do there.

Comment: @naroom - Woops, I did something rather stupid when I was doing the comparison.  I just cast `kernel = kernel.astype(int)`, which, of course, resulted in all zeros.  Integer zero multiplication is a much faster operation than "normal" integer multiplication! At any rate, the speedup is negligible, as you mentioned.

Comment: @unutbu: The two do indeed have different behavior at the borders of the image. So, I fixed that and repeated the test (edited into the code in the question). Matlab's time went up to 8.7 seconds; Python was down to 19 seconds. Progress, but there's still a factor of 2 difference.